# export chart from excel for sending in an email from C# without using interop

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I've server side automation to create some chart in excel using OpenXML. I need to export a chart from my report to an image and send it in an email. The excel libraries are not installed on servers so interop COM is not an option. How can I achieve this without using anything external dlls or anything? Suggestions appreciated. thanks

Comment: without using any "extrnal DLLs" at all you will have to write your own renderer... I doubt that is a viable option though!

Comment: I meant external DLLs is fine if I can ship them with my application. I cant rely on server COM, registered DLLs, etc.. as tI cant install anything on server

Comment: its pretty sad there is no option available here. Solution is a library that can read OpenXML format and render an image.

Comment: the only options I know are commercial libraries (with the proper licensing you can ship them with your application) - is that an option for you ?

Comment: actually no. But can you go ahead and give some links that I can research. I desperately looking for something that will export a graph out of my excel reports to send in an email. I can't come up with any alternative solutions, and I've already promised my clients of the delivery :(

Comment: see my answer below... it has links to 2 commercial libraries which can do what you want (in addition to lots of other stuff like generating a PDF etc.).

Comment: export a chart is a misleading term - try 'rendering', you might get more answers (in the title)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some commercial options to read/edit/create Excel files without Interop which are capable of rendering Charts (among other features):

- [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx)
- [SpreadsheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/)

BTW: [Interop is not supported in sever-scenarios by MS](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257757#kb2).

Comment: If you come across a free library, please let me know. THanks!

Comment: @user236215 I have worked in this area for some time (couple of years) now and never found a free library capable of doing what you want... perhaps someone else know better... wish you luck though...

Answer (score -1):

Try to use [epplus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/).
You can also find it in NuGet.

Comment: Checked. There is no facility of rendering charts to images in EPPlus.